If the localization of a prime ideal of a number ring $R$ is principal, does this imply the prime is invertible?
I am trying to understand the proof of (3) in this theorem, but there is something I just cannot understand.
I will also add a picture of (part of)the proof.

I just don't understand the very last part of this proof. What is proved is that $\mathfrak{p}_i$ is principal and thus invertible as $R_{\mathfrak{p}_i}$ ideal. How does this imply that $R_{\mathfrak{p}_i}$ is a DVR. I know that it being a DVR implies that $\mathfrak{p}_i$ is invertible. I feel like I just don't know or miss some easy fact... Any help is much appreciated.

It would be helpful to say in your post which book the excerpts are taken from and where they are in the book.  By the way, making your question almost entirely text images as you did is discouraged: see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34121/why-image-cannot-be-used-for-explaining-my-maths-problem.

The term number ring, which was introduced in Marcus' book "Number Fields", means the full ring of integers in a number field.  You use it to mean a ring $\mathbf Z[\alpha]$ which need not be that full ring, and indeed this is crucial in the part of  the theorem you ask about, since there are no singular prime ideals when $\mathbf Z[\alpha]$ is the full ring of integers.

A number ring in these lecture notes mean a subring of a number field. In this case it is a Noetherian domain with Krull dimension 1.

My question could be restated as: 'Given Noetherian domain $R$ of dimension 1 and prime/maximal ideal $\mathfrak{p}$. If $\mathfrak{p}R_{\mathfrak{p}}$ is principal does this imply $\mathfrak{p}$ is invertible?' However since I want to understand the proof and not only this question I phrased it like how I did with the pictures.

See Stevenhagen's notes "The arithmetic of number rings" here, especially Theorem 8.2. (His usage of "number ring" matches yours: it need not be a full ring of integers in a number field, but only a subring of finite index in a full ring of integers.) In the proof of Theorem 8.2, the citation of Proposition 5.4 addresses what you ask about: the relation between invertibility and being a DVR.  Corollary 6.2 and Lemma 6.4 here might also interest you.
